# Angular web application codebase for mobile apps?

Tags: django, angular, rest, mobile-application

I want to build a website the following way:

- Backend: Django REST Framework
- Frontend: Angular

I do not want to discard the idea to build mobile apps for Android and iOS in the future as well. I found out that Ionic is a possibility to use an Angular codebase easily for Android and iOS mobile apps. Now my questions:

1. Is that correct and are there alternatives?
2. Can I build my web application with Angular without thinking in mobile apps or do I have to write specific Angular code from the beginning such that I can use the codebase for Android and iOS mobile apps later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it is correct. I don't know of other alternatives
2. you can start with no eye on the ionic specifics. later on when/if you would use mobile platform capabilities like NFC, secure storage, etc you might need to integrate ionic into a project, install, and set up specific plugins. Ionic also has a lot of handy components to make apps look like native ones and not a web app. As you can imagine, if you plan to make the app look native to both iOs and Android, using ionic components would save time in the long run.